# Macro to create a uniquely named OpenMP critical section?

Tags: c++, c, macros, openmp

Several posts explain that it is best to assign names to OpenMP `critical` sections so that their synchronizations do not conflict.
For example, see ["critical" an entire function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682767/critical-an-entire-function/19682797#19682797) or [openMP, atomic vs critical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798010/openmp-atomic-vs-critical/7798994#7798994).

Is it possible to define a macro to create an OpenMP critical section such that it forms a unique name each time the macro is instanced?  (Possibly this could use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`?  However, `__FILE__` is a string?)

Something like:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#define PRAGMA(...) __pragma(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define PRAGMA(...) _Pragma(#__VA_ARGS__) // C++11
#endif

#define BEGIN_LOCK PRAGMA(omp critical (some_incantation_for_a_unique_name))

BEGIN_LOCK { some_code(); }
```

And, why doesn't OpenMP make this the default behavior?  Is there some drawback to this?

Answer (score 0):

If all that you need is that it will be unique in one file, you can use something like the following:

```
#define BEGIN_CRITICAL BEGIN_CRITICAL_1( CRITICAL_, __LINE__)
#define BEGIN_CRITICAL_1(F,L) BEGIN_CRITICAL_2(F,L)
#define BEGIN_CRITICAL_2(F,L)  omp critical(F##L)
```

the first define, adds the 2 parameters (the constant name, and the line number to male it unique.
the second define, expands them.
The 3rd one, concatenates them.

Making it unique in a project, is more difficult, because you need to "un-stringify" `__FILE__` (not sure if this is even possible in pre-processor)...

another option is to have support from your building system: Add to the compilation line `-D`  with the file mane(or any other unique file ID). For example, if you are compiling `foo.cpp`, add `-DMY_FILE=foo.cpp`, and replace the `CRITICAL` in the first macro, with `MY_FILE`

Comment: Thanks.  I was thinking along those lines.  However, this still requires specifying a parameter to the macro (the first parameter `CRITICAL`) that varies per file.

Comment: Or, your build system can do this for you automatically. see update in my answer.